# How to display all data in a table on a form?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a database with a table that contains time,

patien_id
ds001
ds001
ds003
ds003
ds001

sched_time
10:00:00
12:00:00
9:00:00
3:00:00
15:00:00
16:00:00

I can already retrieve the sched_time, my problem is that only one of the sched_time with ds001 patient_id displays.
this is my code:

```
        foreach (DataRow row in _patientSched.Rows)
        {
            schedule1Label.Text = row["sched_time"].ToString();
            schedule2Label.Text = row["sched_time"].ToString();
            schedule3Label.Text = row["sched_time"].ToString();
            schedule5Label.Text = row["sched_time"].ToString();
        }
```

but it only shows the first schedule for all. how can I display all the schedule with the patient_id of ds001?

Comment: add more labels instead of overwriting the same label for each item

Comment: Take a look at ListBox or DataGridView or ListView. That is the control you should be using for this.